# Indian - mother tongue influence

Tags: american-english, subcontinental-english

I'm an Indian who has huge mother tongue influence while speaking English. I have to talk to Americans due to my job.

1. I frequently use "like this only" & "like that only" while speaking to emphasize "we have been doing some actions in certain manner/fashion".
2. I also use "at that time" frequently to convey that "Earlier we have done in that fashion/manner due to certain circumstances"

What are the equivalent phrases used by Americans for the above items?

Comment: Is is feasible for you to ask these questions to the Americans you're interacting with? As it stands, I think we'd need several rounds of questions and answers to arrive at reasonable substitutes for the original expressions.

Comment: I think your colleagues will understand these phrases. If they have to deal with several Indian colleagues, they're used to the fact that there are dialect differences. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided complete lines of dialogue as examples. (But, even so, it's likely this would end up as opinion based or too broad for this site.)